# Advanced Custom Fields dynamic update_field

Tags: custom-field, pages, advanced-custom-fields, child-pages

I have a function that is triggered when a new review is submitted on a specific page.

```
function rex_my_action ($review, $post_id) {

$some_value = get_post_meta( 753, 'rwp_user_score', true );
update_field('gemiddelde_score_hosting_provider', $some_value, 763);

}
add_action('rwp_after_saving_review', 'rex_my_action', 11, 2);
```

When this happens an advanced custom field is updated with the parent_post meta_value rwp_user_score.

The code above is working but I have to fill out the parent Page-ID (753) and child-ID (763) manualy.

I have this page structure:

- Parentpage 1

  - Childpage 1
  - Childpage 2
  - Childpage 3
- Parentpage 2

  - Childpage 1
  - Childpage 2
  - Childpage 3

Etc. Etc.

I think I have to create a for each loop or something because there are more Childpages in a Parent.

So that for each childpage the field 'gemiddelde_score_hosting_provider' gets updated.

Maybe something like this?

```
$some_value = get_post_meta( $post->post_parent, 'rwp_user_score', true );
```

Get all pages with meta_key rwp_user_score but after that I am a bit lost.

What I want is that every child-page with the field 'gemiddelde_score_hosting_provider' gets updated with the value of his parent meta_key 'rwp_user_score'. Manualy I got it working but it would be nice if it can be done dynamicly.

Anybody got a clue?

**EDIT**

Ok, I managed to get it working but I think this function is running all my parent pages with childeren so maybe a bit of an overload?

Is there a way to only check the page_ID(of the parent) and his childeren for the page where the review is submitted?

**This is what I got now:**

```
function rex_my_action ($review, $post_id) {

// Set up the objects needed
$hosting_provider_query = new WP_Query();
global $post;
$hosting_pagina_titel = $post->post_title;  
$doorzoek_alle_paginas = $hosting_provider_query->query(array(
    'post_type' => 'page',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'key' => 'naam_hosting_provivder',
            'value' => $hosting_pagina_titel,
            'compare'   => '='
        ),

    ),
));

// Filter through all pages and find Page's children
$alle_child_paginas_doorlopen = get_page_children( get_the_ID(), $doorzoek_alle_paginas );

// echo what we get back from WP
if(!empty($alle_child_paginas_doorlopen)){
    foreach($alle_child_paginas_doorlopen as $pakket_hp){
        $id_tonen = $pakket_hp->ID;
        $postid = get_queried_object_id();
        $some_value = get_post_meta( $postid, 'rwp_user_score', true );
        update_field('gemiddelde_score_hosting_provider', $some_value, $id_tonen);
    }
}

}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'rex_my_action' );
add_action('rwp_after_saving_review', 'rex_my_action', 11, 2);
```